# Como faço para fechar/encerrar um msgbox via código?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, vb.net

Procurei saber como poderia fazer isto, mas não encontrei nada claro. Quero saber se é possível fechar o primeiro `msgbox`, logo após *2 segundos*.

Segue o Código:

```
MsgBox("Iniciando Conexão Com a Impressora Fiscal", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Conexão")
Retorno = ECF_AbrePortaSerial()
If Retorno = "1" Then
    MsgBox("Conexão Estabelecida!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Ok")
Else
    MsgBox("Erro de Comunicação Com a Impressora Fiscal", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Erro")
    End
End If
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Este `MsgBox()` provavelmente é um legado do VB6. Você não deveria estar usando-o no .NET. Não vai causar nenhum grande problema, mas não faz sentido usá-lo em código novo.

A classe [`MessageBox()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1) do .NET não permite que ela seja fechada programaticamente. Dependendo da necessidade pede uma solução diferente. Vou colocar algumas pela ordem da mais correta para a mais gambiarra. É bom salientar que este tipo de controle não deveria pode ser fechado programaticamente. Não foi esquecimento não ter uma forma de fechar. É um erro tentar fechá-lo.

A primeira solução que você deverá usar se quer um controle que fecha programaticamente é usar outro controle. Não faz sentido usar um controle que não faz o que você deseja. Note que o `MessageBox()` não foi feito para ter várias instâncias. Ele foi criado para bloquear a aplicação, para esperar uma ação nele próprio.

Se quer um controle que funcione quase exatamente como o `MessageBox()`, então crie um controle seu que faça isto e adicione uma forma de fechá-lo programaticamente. Mas o simples fato de colocar essa funcionalidade mostra que o que você quer não é um `MessageBox()`, é um formulário normal que faça algumas coisas específicas.

Há um [projeto no Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17253/A-Custom-Message-Box) que cria uma versão capaz de fechar por código.

Fora isto você pode simular que algo seja enviado para o ambiente para que force o fechamento. você pode [enviar uma tecla](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_SendKeys_Send_System_String_) para o controle.

Existe ainda a possibilidade de capturar o comportamento das mensagens do Windows em um nível mais baixo que o Windows Forms e enviar um `WM_CLOSE`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Entendi, agradeço pela resposta ! 
Irá ajudar.

Answer (score 7):

Você pode utilizar a função [`MessageBoxTimeout`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/MessageBoxTimeout.html), ela não foi documentada pela Microsoft.

Veja um [exemplo em C#](http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=69236):

```c-sharp
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
//..
class MessageBoxTimer{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int MessageBoxTimeout(IntPtr hwnd, String text, String title, uint type, Int16 wLanguageId, Int32 milliseconds);

    public enum MessageBoxReturnStatus{
        OK = 1, Cancel = 2, Abort = 3, Retry = 4, Ignore = 5, Yes = 6, 
        No = 7, TryAgain = 10, Continue = 11
    }

    public enum MessageBoxType{
        OK = 0, OK_Cancel = 1, Abort_Retry_Ignore = 2,
        Yes_No_Cancel = 3, Yes_No = 4,
        Retry_Cancel = 5, Cancel_TryAgain_Continue = 6
    }

    public MessageBoxReturnStatus Show(string title, string text, MessageBoxType type, int milliseconds){
        int returnValue = MessageBoxTimeout(IntPtr.Zero, text, title, Convert.ToUInt32(type), 1, milliseconds);
        return (MessageBoxReturnStatus)returnValue;
    }
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```c-sharp
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    MessageBoxTimer msg = new MessageBoxTimer();
    msg.Show("MessageBox Timeout", "Essa mensagem vai fechar em 5 segundos", 0, 5000);       
}
```