# MessageBox com autoclose

Tags: c#, winforms, thread

Estou tendo alguns problemas com um aplicativo que eu criei, usando `C#` e `Windows Forms`, e a situação é a seguinte:

1. O aplicativo é um chat. Ele não guarda registro das conversas;
2. Quando o aplicativo é fechado eu solicito uma confirmação para fechamento informando que todo o conteúdo da converse será perdido;
3. O chat fica ativo no tray até que o usuário tente fechá-lo clicando com o botão esquerdo no ícone;

Quando o usuário tenta desligar o PC sem antes desligar o chat o windows fica sempre na tela de "Preparando para finalizar", aguardando o encerramento dos processos pendentes e nunca sai desta tela sem que o usuário "Force" o encerramento.

Eu acredito que este comportamento ocorra devido à esta mensagem de confirmação que bloqueia a `thread`.

O que eu desejo fazer é algo do tipo:

Solicitar a confirmação, porém caso o usuário não responda nada dentro de 30 segundos, por exemplo, a confirmação seja fechada automaticamente e o aplicativo encerre.

Porém ao usar o `MessageBox.Show()` o usuário deve sempre responder para encerrar o processo.

Pensei em desenvolver um form para fazer esta notificação, porém não sei como simular o comportamento do `MessageBox.Show()` bloqueando a `thread` da UI e ainda verificar um `timer` para saber se o tempo já passou.

Qualquer ajuda que me leve a atingir o meu objetivo e deixar os usuários mais "Feliz" será muito bem vinda.

Comment: Veja se ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50873/como-fa%C3%A7o-para-fechar-encerrar-um-msgbox-via-c%C3%B3digo/50878#50878

Comment: Vou testar, mas acredito que vá suprir a minha necessidade. Vlw

Comment: @HStackOverflow Poste seu comentário como resposta.

Comment: Obrigado @PauloHDSousa, se resolver o problema dele acho melhor ele avaliar a resposta (do link) senão fica repetitivo. Mesmo assim caso o autor ache a resposta (do comentário) útil posso mudar.

Answer (score 1):

Infelizmente, o MessageBox não implementa um Timer. Mas você pode fazer um form de diálogo que atenda às suas necessidades. Para isso você pode criar um form em modo design com um label para mostrar a mensagem e dois botões, um Sim e outro Não. No exemplo vou chamar esse form de MensagemConfirmacao.

Substitua o construtor desse novo form por isso:

```
public MensagemConfirmacao(string msg){
    this.lblMensagem = msg;
    Timer timer = new Timer(); // cria um temporizador para fechar o form
    timer.interval = 30000; // 30000 milisegundos para executar
    timer.Tick += delegate { // atribui o evento Tick ao timer
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes; // Atribui DialogResult ao form. Isso 
                                              // fecha o formulário
    }
    timer.Start(); // inicia o timer
}
```

Com isso, você fecha o formulário depois do tempo definido pelo Timer.

No botão SIM você coloca o mesmo código do evento Tick, ou seja:

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes;
```

E no botão não:

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.No;
```

Lembrando que quando setamos o DialogResult de um form, o mesmo é fechado automaticamente.

Para chamar este form, coloque no evento OnClosing do Formulário principal:

```
using (MensagemConfirmacao msg = new MensagemConfirmacao("COLOQUE AQUI O TEXTO A SER EXIBIDO"))
{
     if (msg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.No)
        e.cancel = true; // nesse caso, "e" é o nome do parametro EventArgs do Metodo     
                         // Form_Closing
}
```

Qualquer dúvida é só perguntar.